# Using large $\lambda$ value when the orginal one was suitable for Poisson

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

**Please read the question carefully to prevent unnecessary comments!**

I know that the real value and poission distribution is getting closer and closer when $n$ is large and $p$ is small. Generally , books say that it is good to use poison when $\lambda < 7$ .

I wonder something such that there are some types of question :

> On the average there are $6$ no-shows per airplane flight. If there are
> $10$ flights scheduled, find the prob of $4$ no-shows

> Solution: If there are $6$ no-shows per airplane flight , then there are $60$ no-shows for ten flights. Hence , our $\lambda$ is $60$ $$P(4)=\frac{(60)^4e^{-60}}{4!}$$

This is a classical Poisson distribution question. However , something stuck in my mind. In the beginning  , our $\lambda$ was $6$ , and it was suitable value for applying Poisson , but we used $\lambda =60 $ to apply Poisson for ten flight. My question is that if the real value and the result of Poisson get diverging for large $\lambda$ such as $\lambda > 7$  , is  using $\lambda =60$ a good idea ?

Comment: Not following.  If you are using Poisson (not "poison") then you have to get the average right, so of course you'd take $\lambda=60$.  Is that a good estimator?  Well, it depends on what model you have in mind.  If you knew the number of ticketed passengers in a flight you could try to use a binomial distribution (though of course there are a lot of assumptions there as well).

Comment: But the problem seems weird.  If you expect $6$ per flight then the probability of observing $≤4$ in $10$ flights is $0$.  No computation needed for that estimate.

Comment: I would read the problem as asking for the chance that at least one (or maybe precisely one)  of $10$ flights has precisely $4$ no-shows but not be sure about it.  In that case you use $\lambda=6$ for one flight to get the chance of $4$ on one flight, then use binomial to get the chance for $10$ flights.

Comment: @lulu i made up the question , so you can think also for $P(12)$ etc. That point is not important. What important is that i cannot understand why very large lambda values can be used , because when lambda get larger , the real value (obtained from binom) and Poisson value diverging.

Comment: @lulu i made up the question , so you can think also for $P(12)$ etc. That point is not important. What important is that i cannot understand why very large lambda values can be used , because when lambda get larger , the real value (obtained from binom) and Poisson value diverging.

Comment: @lulu i made up the question , so you can think also for $P(12)$ etc. That point is not important. What important is that i cannot understand why very large lambda values can be used , because when lambda get larger , the real value (obtained from binom) and Poisson value diverging.

Comment: As I say, it clearly depends on the model you are using.  If you believe that no-shows are drawn from a Poisson distribution (and you believe that each flight has the same number of ticketed passengers) then of course you must scale $\lambda$ accordingly.  If you believe something else, then your estimation may change.

Comment: @lulu if the original average were $60$ , then using the Poisson would be dangerous. However , the average for ten flight is $60$ , then there is not a problem for using.. This is what i stuck in

Comment: @RossMillikan  if the original average were $60$ , then using the Poisson would be dangerous. However , the average for ten flight is $60$ , then there is not a problem for using.. This is what i stuck in

Comment: I feel like I am just repeating myself:  "dangerous" is subjective.  It can only make sense in reference to some other model which one assumes to be Truth, but you have not stated any such model here.  If you have a model you trust, use that.  Then you can compare it to whatever approximation you wish to use. There aren't universal answers here.